# Python スクリプトの実行時、指定した CSV ファイルが見つからない

Tags: python

Python初学者です。
VScodeのPython3.8.8環境でpandasライブラリを使用していて、read_csvでcsvファイルを読み込もうとしているのですが、FileNotFoundErrorが出てしまいます。
画像のpyファイルとtest.csvファイルは同一のディレクトリ内に存在しています。
対処法に心当たりのある方はご教授いただけると幸いです。

[image]

Comment: 画像の py ファイルと `test.csv` の内容を、画像ではなくテキストとして質問文に追加していただけませんか？

Comment: こちらの記事が参考になりそうです。[ファイルのディレクトリで実行する](https://jade.alt-area.jp/archives/569#i-6), VSCodeの元の説明 [cwd](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_cwd)  あるいはこんな記事も。[Python in VSCode: Set working directory to python file's path everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56776521/9014308)

Answer (score 1):

おそらく、Python を起動しているディレクトリとスクリプトファイルが置かれているディレクトリが異なっているのだと思います。スクリプトファイルと CSV ファイルが同じディレクトリにあるのであれば、以下の様にするとよいのではないでしょうか。

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

csv_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'test.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
```